# Subviews in dispatch_async appears after a long delay

Tags: ios, delay, subviews, dispatch-async

I've used dispatch_async to put in background a xml document's parsing, I've putted information in an array and, with a for cycle, I would assign the content of every element to an UILabel (for now), the problem is that in the output console I can see the right content of every element but the uilabel are added only in the end after a long delay.

Code:

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData *xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error;
    GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:&error];
    NSArray *areaCortina = [doc nodesForXPath:@"query" error:nil];

    int i=0;
    for (GDataXMLElement *element in areaCortina) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[[element attributeForName:@"LiftName"] stringValue]); //data are shown correctly 

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (30+10)*i, 200, 30)];// don't appear after log
        [label setText:[[element attributeForName:@"name"] stringValue]];
        [self.view performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addSubview:) withObject:label waitUntilDone:YES];

        i++;
  }
```

As you can see i've used performSelectorOnMainThread but nothig, the label doesn't appear once at once but are shown correctly only after a 10 or 15 seconds after the end of the block.

Ideas?

Thanks in advance

**Ok edit 1**

Thanks to the advice of Shimanski Artem I've now the following:

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

...    

dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData *xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error;
    GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:&error];
    NSArray *areaCortina = [doc nodesForXPath:@"query" error:nil];
    self.data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  

    for (GDataXMLElement *element in areaCortina) {
        [self.data addObject:[[element attributeForName:@"name"] stringValue]]; 

    }
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"name" object:self];
 }

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(caricaItem) name:@"name" object:nil];

 ...

} //end method


-(void) caricaItem
{
int i=0;
for (NSString * string in self.dati) {

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, (30+10)*i, 200, 30)];
    [label setText:string];

    [self.view addSubview:label];

    i++;
}
```

}

I've put uilabels creation out of dispatch, in the caricaItem method where i've ready an array full of precious data, but same delay... and the same if in caricaItem i use a UITableView...

What is the right way to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});` instead of `performSelectorOnMainThread` ?

Comment: Simple rule: don't call UI methods in non-main thread. Move UILabel creation to main thread.

Comment: Thanks guys for the advices, i've updated with new code